# How to make a list data with Observablecollection to show in listbox

Tags: c#, mvvm, listbox

I use MVVM to dev my app. 
[Table]Member with [Column] FullName | Address

I want to list all FullName to show in Listbox dont know how... When I click Show...the line "Library.Model.Member" appears...(Library is my project's name)

**my Add function in ViewModel**

```
 public void Add(Member info)
      {
          MemberDB.Members.InsertOnSubmit(info);
          MemberDB.SubmitChanges();
          Data.Add(info); 

      }
```

**In my Show.xaml.cs**

```
 public Show()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = App.ViewModel;

    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save changes to the database.
        App.ViewModel.SaveChangesToDB();
    }
```

**Listbox:**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <ListBox x:Name="FullName"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
           FontSize="30">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
        </Listbox>
        </StackPanel>
```

**Data**

```
private ObservableCollection<Member> _data;
    public ObservableCollection<Member> Data
    {
        get { if(_data==null)
            _data = new ObservableCollection<Member>();
                return _data;
        }
        set 
        {
            if(value !=_data)
            _data = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the ListBox an ItemTemplate, by default it has a ListBoxItem and it tried to do ToString() on your object.

Something like this

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource customers}" Width="350" Margin="0,5,0,10">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0"
      Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Text=", " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```